# How to add multiple authenticators in AdonisJs

Tags: javascript, adonis.js

In my AdonisJs project, I use session authentication. Now I want to add JWT authentication, but I do not have multiple authenticators in my authenticator file.

File: `project/config/auth.js`

Example: `authenticator: 'session'`

How to I add multiple authenticators?

Comment: Might help: https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/authentication#_switching_authenticators

Comment: single authenticator work okay. but multiple not working

Comment: "but multiple" ->
can you please share an example (I don't really understand the problem . What @SunnyRGupta said should solve the problem). Thanks